# Releasing ETH from Escrow Smart Contract Back to Original Party

Tags: contract-development, ether

What is the best way to refund ETH from Escrow Smart Contract to the original party on an Ethereum blockchain?

I created a smart contract which allows one party to submit a specified amount of ETH, to be held until they release it at a later time. A second party should be able to cancel the transaction, releasing the full amount back to the first party. Is refunding this escrow type of scenario possible without losing gas fees? It seems gas is taken when setupSale is executed. I don't want the attendees to take the hit if the host cancels, but I also don't want the host to refund all of the attendees' gas if they need to cancel an event due to factors beyond their control.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED


  /**
   * @title Attend
   * @dev Payer allows funds to be held and released to a host.
   * @custom:dev-run-script /contracts/1_Attend.sol
   */

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Attend
{
    struct Sale {
        uint saleId;
        address host;
        address attendee;
        uint initialValue;
        uint remainingValue;
        bool locked; 
    }

    Sale[] sales;
    address platform;
    uint remainingAmount;

    constructor(address _platform) {
        platform = _platform;
    }

    function setupSale (
        uint _saleId,
        address payable _host
        ) payable public {

        require(_host != msg.sender, "Host cannot be attendee.");
        
        Sale memory newSale = Sale(
            _saleId,  
            _host,
            msg.sender,
            msg.value,
            msg.value,
            false
            );

        bool exists = false;

        for (uint i = 0; i<sales.length; i++) {
            if (sales[i].saleId == _saleId) {
                exists = true;
            }
        }

        require(!exists, "Sale already exists in the system.");   

        sales.push(newSale);        
    }

    function releaseFunds(uint _saleId) public {
        (uint saleIndex, Sale memory sale) = getSale(_saleId);
        require(sale.saleId != 0, "Sale ID is invalid. Cannot release funds.");
        require(sale.attendee == msg.sender, "Only the attendee may release funds.");
        releasePlatformFunds(sale.saleId);
        releaseHostFunds(sale.saleId);
        deleteSale(saleIndex);
    }

    function releasePlatformFunds(uint _saleId) internal {
        (uint saleIndex, Sale memory sale) = getSale(_saleId);
        uint256 platformFee = sale.initialValue * 1/20;
        (bool platSent,) = platform.call{value:platformFee}("");
        require(platSent, "Failed to release funds for platform fee.");
        sales[saleIndex].remainingValue = sales[saleIndex].initialValue - platformFee;
    }

    function releaseHostFunds(uint _saleId) internal {
        (uint saleIndex, Sale memory sale) = getSale(_saleId);
        uint256 fee = sales[saleIndex].remainingValue;
        (bool hostSent,) = sale.host.call{value:fee}("");
        require(hostSent, "Failed to release funds to host.");
    }

    function returnFunds(uint _saleId) public {
        (uint saleIndex, Sale memory sale) = getSale(_saleId);
        require(sale.saleId != 0, "Sale ID is invalid. Cannot return funds.");
        require(sale.attendee == msg.sender, "Only the attendee may return funds.");
        (bool fundsReturned,) = msg.sender.call{value:sale.initialValue}("");
        require(fundsReturned, "Returning funds failed.");
        deleteSale(saleIndex);
    }

    function refundFunds(uint _saleId) public {
        (uint saleIndex, Sale memory sale) = getSale(_saleId);
        require(sale.saleId != 0, "Sale ID is invalid. Cannot refurn funds.");
        require(sale.host == msg.sender, "Only the host may return funds.");
        (bool fundsReturned,) = sale.attendee.call{value:sale.initialValue}("");
        require(fundsReturned, "Refunding funds failed.");
        deleteSale(saleIndex);
    }

    function getSalesLength() internal view returns(uint) {
        return sales.length;
    }
    
    function getSale(uint _saleId) internal view returns(uint index, Sale memory sale) {
        for (uint i=0; i<getSalesLength(); i++) {
            if (sales[i].saleId == _saleId) {
                return (i, sales[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteSale(uint _index) internal {
        sales[_index] = sales[getSalesLength() - 1];
        sales.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since there's no standard for escrow contract it will depend on the particular contract implementation.  Share the source code if you want more details.

Comment: I rewrote the question and included source code.

Comment: The transaction fees pays the network usage, smart contract processing and storage, so there's no way to return all of those fees. You'll get a small refund by resetting the used storage slots.